# Replace a <div> with another (in Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently i have this (in a function):

```
$('#Ligne' + Ligne_Doublons).remove(); //Remove the Div
$('#Panier').append('<div id=\'Ligne' + Ligne_Doublons + '\'><div class="ABC">' + Qte + '</div><div class="ABC">' + Nom + '</div></div>'); //Add de New Div
```

Example :

I have 3 div :

```
<div 1>
<div 2>
<div 3>
```

After the function who change the "div 2", the code make this:

```
<div 1>
<div 3>
<New div 2>
```

But i want this :

```
<div 1>
<New div 2>
<div 3>
```

Do you know how i can make this?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Can we see your **valid** HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

```
$('#Ligne' + Ligne_Doublons)
    .replaceWith('<div id=\'Ligne' + Ligne_Doublons + '\'><div class="ABC">' + Qte + '</div><div class="ABC">' + Nom + '</div></div>')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method:

```
$('selector_to_div_1').after('div_2');
```

Comment: Beat me by 10 seconds.

Comment: why not `.replaceWith`? `$('#div2').replaceWith('<New div 2>');`

Comment: @DevlshOne yeah I agree that replacewith is better, it just didn't pop up in my mind fast enough :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace div 2 with another one.

Let's say you have the following HTML code

```
<div class="element-1"></div>
<div class="element-2"></div>
<div class="element-3"></div>
```

Then the jQuery code should be as following:

```
$('element-2').replaceWith($('<div class="new-element-2"></div>');
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the contents and data/events attached to the contents then try

```
$('#d2').replaceWith(function(){
    return $('<div />').append($(this).contents())
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/usR7p/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is you're removing a div, then trying to append a new div *after* the one you've just removed.

Therefore, if you append the *new* div to the old one, then remove the old one it should be in the right place.